# Reduce cpu cost of readyRead() when using high speed internet connection

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I tried to profiling my program, which is a file downloader. I use 5 `QNetworkRequest` to enhance transfer speed, they all connect to the same  `readyRead()` slot.

I use QMap to buffer those byte arrays.

When downloading speed reaches, e.g 5 MiB/s, I found CPU costs rises up significantly, nearly 100%, `readyRead()` was calling 30 times per seconds.

Is there any suggestion to this, e.g can I let QNetworkReply buffer its io device, reduce the amount of signals emitted?

**UPDATA**

I made some debug output in readyReady():
(`reply` here was casted from sender())

`qDebug() << "Got: " << reply->readAll().length() << " bytes";`

And about 30 output per seconds , each contains 1500 bytes

Comment: Can you show your `readReady` code? 30 calls/sec doesn't seem really huge.

Comment: @Mat https://github.com/CaledoniaProject/Transf0r-Mini/blob/master/downloader.cpp#L406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one hint after quick look on your code. You're using `QByteArray::append` member (`downloadBuffers`) which realocates internal buffer for appended data. If you're able to predict how much data you will store in each download buffer then use `QByteArray::reserve` with exact amount of data. If you can't you could simply reserve i.e. 1mb and reserve memory progresively 1mb each time your next append will exceed current `QByteArray::capacity`. You can for example reserve `downbufferSize` for each buffer. It's a slight optimization, but should give you some time

Comment: That's of great help , but , had to ask: what's difference between `resize()` and `reserve()` here , i'm not sure if it's same with C++ STL(Vector) .. document is pretty confusing to me

Comment: reserve resizes internal buffer, but keeps QByteArray to think that it has same ammount of data as it had before doing reserve. Resize resizes internal buffer and tells QByteArray that it contains `size` bytes (of uninitialized data)